# Is using processor usage for the automated scheduling of processes a good practice?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, windows-server-2008

I've been having a debate of sorts with a co-worker who suggested that we allow some cpu intensive processes in our enterprise to poll CPU usage and execute their tasks when the CPU usage is low.  My counter-point was that while cpu usage in an ideal system would denote the level of system activity on a given server, in actuality it has too much inconsistency(peaks and dips over a short time) in a real system to be an effective indicator of when a cpu intensive process should run.  And in addition I stated that the OS is designed to manage processor contention between threads and applications already.  My suggestion was simply to run the process afterhours to avoid degrading the user's experience during the day.

**My question is, can cpu usage be an effective indicator as to when processes should run in an enterprise setting?  It would be a nice-to-know if I'm right, sort of right, or just being incorrect...**

Edit: These applications are .NET services as well as SQL Server scheduled jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it isn't (so yes you are correct).

There are many ways that it can cause problems, off the top of my head:

- The OS is attempting to balance
  resource allocation. In order to do
  this it has a scheduling algorithm
  that uses a view of the current
  resource usage. What you describe is
  running a second scheduling algorithm
  that will fight with the first one
  (the OS scheduler) over allocation of
  CPU. This can cause strange feedback
  effects.
- Just using process usage doesn't take
  into account other resources such as
  memory. When one process runs it
  doesn't just display other processes
  by using processor cycles. It's
  working set of data is fighting with
  other processes to be kept in memory
  and out of swap. You can seriously
  degrade the performance (and latency
  especially) of other processes if you
  activate your task because the CPU is
  not in use and it causes their data
  to be paged out.
- Why reinvent the wheel? This is
  precisely what priority levels /
  idle-processing were invented for. If
  you just want your process to take up
  background CPU then set it running at
  the lowest priority level and allow
  the OS to schedule it.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be the *lowest* priority, just one step down should be enough if it is work you want doing soon (just after other things). Some things are really background: they should have an even lower priority.

Comment: The use that Achilles describes is background. What do you think would be lower priority?